# Marking a referenced library class in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, service

This is in relation to a previous question I asked:

I have a DLL defining a Transaction class. It is referenced by a WCF service library as well as a client application. I get errors stating that the service library cannot be hosted because it can't serialise the DLL class.

Here's the service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using ServerLibrary.MarketService;
using SharedLibrary; // This is the DLL in question

namespace ServerLibrary
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);

        [OperationContract]
        CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite);

        [OperationContract]
        bool ProcessTransaction(SharedLibrary.Transaction transaction);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class CompositeType
    {
        bool boolValue = true;
        string stringValue = "Hello ";

        [DataMember]
        public bool BoolValue
        {
            get { return boolValue; }
            set { boolValue = value; }
        }

        [DataMember]
        public string StringValue
        {
            get { return stringValue; }
            set { stringValue = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Do I have to mark the Transaction class here with [attribute] headers?

[UPDATE]

Here's the error messages I get when I try to host this service:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type
>   'SharedLibrary.Transaction' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it
>   with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. 
>   If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String
>   message, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32
>   id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.GetSchemaTypeName(Type
>   type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.ValidateDataContractType(Type
>   type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.CreatePartInfo(MessagePartDescription
>   part, OperationFormatStyle style,
>   DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerFactory)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.CreateMessageInfo(DataContractFormatAttribute
>   dataContractFormatAttribute, MessageDescription messageDescription,
>   DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerFactory)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription
>   description, DataContractFormatAttribute dataContractFormatAttribute,
>   DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerFactory)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.GetFormatter(OperationDescription
>   operation, Boolean& formatRequest, Boolean& formatReply, Boolean
>   isProxy)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(OperationDescription
>   description, DispatchOperation dispatch)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription
>   contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.InitializeServiceHost(ServiceDescription
>   description, ServiceHostBase serviceHost)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnBeginOpen()    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
>   at Microsoft.Tools.SvcHost.ServiceHostHelper.OpenService(ServiceInfo
>   info)

As requested here is the DLL containing Transaction:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SharedLibrary
{
    // Transaction class to encapsulate products and checkout data
    public class Transaction
    {
            public int checkoutID;
            public DateTime time;
            public List<object> products; // Using object to avoid MarketService reference, remember to cast back!
            public double totalPrice;
            public bool complete;

            public Transaction(int ID)
            {
                checkoutID = ID;
            }

            public void Start()
            {
                products = new List<object>();
                complete = false;
            }

            public void Complete()
            {
                time = DateTime.Now;
                complete = true;
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What version of C# / WCF are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET 4 if that helps.

Comment: Can you add the definition of `SharedLibrary.Transaction`?

Comment: Sure, updated with Transaction.

Comment: Can you add a default constructor without any params and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to mark the Transaction class here with [attribute] headers?

No, you shouldn't have to, but it is recommended. See [Using Data Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx).

---

The problem is that you are passing derived objects in a `List<object>`.

You have to tell the service what type objects to handle with a [ServiceKnownType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceknowntypeattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[OperationContract]
[ServiceKnownType( typeof( MarketService.XXX ) )]
bool ProcessTransaction(SharedLibrary.Transaction transaction);
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas but I'm still getting the same error. I applied MarketService.Product as typeof() which is what the list of objects will be.

Comment: The next thing to try is sending a `Transaction` object through with no items in the `products` List. Also, are you getting any other errors?

Comment: I can't get to the point of actually passing objects. These errors occur when I try to build the WCF service library and visual studio automatically hosts it. There are no new errors other than the failure to serialise the SharedLibrary.Transaction class.

Comment: Ah OK. What happens if you take the `products` field out altogether?

Comment: I've commented out the product list in the Transaction class and references to it elsewhere in the library and in the Service and IService classes. I've uploaded a screenshot of the error: http://i46.tinypic.com/izysme.jpg

Comment: That doesn't make sense!! Something else is going on. I suggest you start taking things out until you find the real cause.

Comment: I know it is baffling. I've started from scratch with a new visual studio solution and manage to get the host working by using [OperationBehavior] attributes but my original problem trying to get the client's Transaction class to be interoperable with the service's Transaction has resurfaced. I just need a way for a checkout client to send transaction objects to the service and it's proving much more difficult than I anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to define your transaction class as below

```
[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(MarketService.XXX))]
public class Transaction
{
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I added this to the IService namespace but the errors remain. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: You may want to do this at the Transaction class level. Try it.